# Creating Custom Expandable textview

Tags: android, layout, view, textview, expandablelistadapter

I want to create an `Expandable TextView`, like what we get in message threads. The size of the `TextView` is not fixed but depends upon the text length and number of lines. It also has borders which expand (or multiply) depending on the size of the text to show.

How to set such layout ??


can someone help me in this regard!

thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem with wrap_content is with the increase in size of the text (like number of lines >15), the quality of bgimage deteriorates.
OK it may be fixed with a very high quality image but the text padding and all are wrecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a tile image like those that are used in webpages..they are light and they are repeated using the CSS-REPEAT tag....similar effect in android also exists  using the `android:titlemode` which has the following [image]
repeat
clamp
mirror

- **So how will it solve your problem**
  You make a single message's background image that can be a graphic of size 100x1 so repeating this image will give a nice colour to your message thread using the `android:tilemode`

Check this image using such but a smaller one can help you repeat it in your message thread background

Answer (score 0):

use these properties.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: the problem with wrap_content is with the increase in size of the text (like number of lines >15), the quality of bgimage deteriorates. OK it may be fixed with a very high quality image but the text padding and all are wrecked.